# What is the correct way of defining an Intent variable?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm writing an Android service that logs the app name when you open it. However, I keep getting the error that "Symbol not found", I searched and learned this means I haven't correctly asigned the intent variable or I am using it out of the scope. Is that correct? If so, how do I fix it?

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.myapplication.AppLoggerService;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Start the service
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AppLoggerService.class);

        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "Symbol not found" typically means that the variable or class you are using is not in scope or has not been properly imported. In your case, you haven't imported the Intent class that you are using to create the intent.

To fix this, just add this import statement at the top of your code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
```

However, you usually get some warnings for these kind of things, so I'm guessing you either missed the warning, or it's something else entirely.